# How to fix "Broken Pipe" error when trying to write a named pipe?

Tags: rust, pipe, named-pipes

I'm experimenting with named pipes in rust, and I want to create a server that receives the messages from a client that never ends.

```
//reciever.rs
use libc::{c_char, mkfifo};
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let _ = std::fs::remove_file("rust-fifo");
    let name_fifo = CString::new("rust-fifo").unwrap();
    let name_fifo: *const c_char = name_fifo.as_ptr() as *const c_char;

    if unsafe { mkfifo(name_fifo, 0o644) } != 0 {
        panic!("Error creating fifo.")
    }

    loop {
        let mut file = OpenOptions::new().read(true).open("rust-fifo").unwrap();
        let mut buffer = Vec::new();
        file.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        //println!("{:#?}", &buffer);
        println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap());
    }
}
```

```
//sender.rs
use std::{fs::OpenOptions, io::Write};

fn main() {
    loop {
        let mut file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open("rust-fifo").expect("error opening the file");
        file.write_all(b"hello").expect("error writing the file");//ERROR HERE "BROKEN PIPE"
    }
}
```

`receiver.rs` receives some messages but then `sender.rs` throws error,when not using the loop everything works fine, but i want to have a client that never ends, this is the error,why it happens?

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'error writing the file: Os { code: 32, kind: BrokenPipe, message: "Broken pipe" }', src/bin/sender.rs:6:34
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why it happens?

The `broken pipe` means: you've tried to write to a pipe which (currently) has
no reader.

In the receiver, you are constantly closing and re-opening the FIFO. If the sender tries to write between the receiver `close` and `open`, it will get the   `EPIPE` error from `write(2)`.

So don't do that -- open the FIFO *once* and keep reading messages from it.

Comment: thank you very much, it makes a lot of sense, i will try to implement it!